# Integration test and Cucumber test

Tags: android, cucumber, instrumentation

I have a project where I'm running android instrumentation tests with an `AndroidJunitRunner`.

I'm now adding UI automated tests using Cucumber. How can I keep both Cucumber tests that use a runner that extends `MonitoringInstrumentation` and the other instrumentation tests that use a runner that extends `AndroidJunitRunner?

In the `build.gradle` I used to have

```
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.packagename.packagename2.MockedTestRunner"
```

now I have:

```
    testApplicationId "com.packagename.packagename2.test"
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.packagename.packagename2.test.Instrumentation"
```

Do I need to create a second module to run the cucumber tests?

Comment: Maybe this one can help. https://rominirani.com/gradle-tutorial-part-3-multiple-java-projects-5b1c4d1fbd8d

Answer (score 2):

**To enable Android Test Orchestrator using the Gradle command-line    tool, complete these steps:**

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
   ...
   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   // The following argument makes the Android Test Orchestrator run its
   // "pm clear" command after each test invocation. This command ensures
   // that the app's state is completely cleared between tests.
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
 }

  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
}

dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
  androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.0'
}
```

2. Run Android Test Orchestrator by executing the

   ./gradlew connectedCheck

**Enable from Android Studio**
Support for Android Test Orchestrator is available with Android Studio 3.0 and higher. To enable Android Test Orchestrator in Android Studio, add the statements shown in [Enable from Gradle](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#ato-gradle) to your app's build.gradle file.